# Sintaxe para executar codigo[ERRO]

Tags: php, html, css

```
$mensagem  = '


<div style="font-size:17px; color: #707070; font-weight:bold; font-family: 'Segoe UI Semibold','Segoe UI Bold','Segoe UI','Helvetica Neue Medium',Arial,sans-serif; "  > Conta da Microsoft </div>

';
```

Pessoal na parte font-family: ', como eu digito isso para que não dê erro?

Eu não sei o que fazer aí pq ficou aspas simples dentro de aspas duplas, até aí ok, mas , depois preciso usar mais aspas e tá dando erro assim:

```
 Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'Segoe' (T_STRING) in /storage/ssd3/793/15779793/public_html/enviar.php on line 5
```

Comment: Olá Optimus. Aonde esta aspas simples `'Segoe UI Semibold','Segoe UI Bold','Segoe UI','Helvetica Neue Medium'` tem que ser "escapado", assim `\'Segoe UI Semibold\',\'Segoe UI Bold\',\'Segoe UI\',\'Helvetica Neue Medium\'`. Recomendo que antes de usar uma linguagem aprenda o "básico do básico", segue o link: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php. Obrigado pela atenção.